# Larger payloads with content and accept encoding headers

Tags: node.js, rest, express, http-headers

I have a use-case where,

1. I make a POST request to a REST API from client server with a payload of size 20-30MB, the request header contains content-encoding set to gzip, so it gets compressed at the n/w level
2. In addition to this, do I need to enable gzip compression at the API level?
3. Now, assuming that the above POST request succeeded in writing that larger payload to the database, and when I try to retrieve the data back to the client which is again a POST request (that is how it's been designed, make a POST request to retrieve data), do i need to set the POST request header that retrieves data to accept-encoding: gzip

The REST API is a node/express application and the database is cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how this works.

> the request header contains content-encoding set to gzip, so it gets compressed at the n/w level

This means your client is compressing the payload. Not the network. The `content-encoding` HTTP header tells the other side what format the body is being sent in, not what format you would like the body to be sent in. Typically a HTTP client, server or library handles all this for you.

> In addition to this, do I need to enable gzip compression at the API level?

No. If the client is compressing it already, in the client code (perhaps using a standard HTTP library), there is nothing to be gained from compressing it again in your code.

> Now, assuming that the above POST request succeeded in writing that larger payload to the database, and when I try to retrieve the data back to the client which is again a POST request (that is how it's been designed, make a POST request to retrieve data), do i need to set the POST request header that retrieves data to accept-encoding: gzip

If your client can handle gzip, then it should automatically set `accept-encoding: gzip`. Then if your server can deliver it gzipped, it will. The `accept-encoding` header is a an optional bit of information the client can send to let the server know of the client's capabilities. It is a hint ("Hey I can accept gzipped responses so use that if you want") and is **not** an order that must be obeyed (i.e. it is not "You must send me this in gzip format").

How the file is actually stored at the server is entirely dependent on your app, but typically it would be stored unzipped and that way it can be delivered to clients who don't handle gzip, or those that do, or those that handle other compression formats like brotli. The web server typically then compresses on the fly based on the `accept-encoding` header in the request.